# Send push notification to user when they go to certain location [IOS]

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications, location, push

So I'm using Parse for my back-end. I basically want to be able to send a user a push notification when the user enters a certain location. Let's say, When i go into town i'd like to get a notification saying "Welcome to Town" or something like that. Is this possible to do on ios and with parse?

Comment: Why a push? Why not a local notification?

Comment: I haven't done much with local notification. Would this be a better option? and Could this work even if the person is not using the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want isn't a push notification. Look at `UILocalNotification.region` and the `CLRegion` class.

Comment: Thanks Wain I appreciate that. I'll do some research into it.